# VMs detailed properties using azure?

Tags: powershell, azure

is there any way to get all VM's expanded properties and not just the ones Get-azurermvm brings, using powershell?
I was trying to use Select but I don't know where to get all the names. The ones on the Portal's Column won't work (bring back empty fields)
and if I use get-member, they don't bring anything because I think they are nested inside...

Comment: All of the properties? See, here's the thing, Azure VMs aren't really self contained. They're more a collection of objects, such as Azure Network Interfaces, so I think in order to really help you here we'd need to know what all you are looking to obtain.

Comment: . I thought so but I don't know how to bring the parameters inside the objects. The idea would be to get at least all the columns you can set in the portal for a VM:
Instance IP address
Private IP address
Resource type
Size
Network interfaces
Operating system
Public DNS name
Public IP address
Resource group
Subnet
Subscription ID
Virtual IP address
Resource group ID
Virtual network
Availability set
Disk encryption
Disks
Kind
Load balanced set
Location
Location ID
Resource ID
Status
Subscription
Type
Uses managed disks

And custom Tags

Comment: Are you trying to get these details, or are you creating a VM, and trying to specify these details?

Comment: Im trying to get these details and export them to a csv to inventory everything.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is not trivial because an Azure VM is not a self contained thing like a Hyper-V VM. There is no single source of truth because it is made of many components, and you would need to collect the information from those components individually. For example: Getting all of a VM's IP addresses.

To start getting IPs for a machine you get the VM info:

```
$VM = Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroup $RG -Name 'MyUberVM'
```

Now you can look at the network profile for the VM, which will list the Network Interface objects that are associated with VM, but those have all of 2 properties, Primary and Id. The Primary property is just what it sounds like, it specifies the primary network interface if you have more than one. The Id property will have the full ResourceId for the Network Interface object, something like:

```
/subscriptions/12345abc-0000-1111-2222-ssl430asd432/resourceGroups/MyVMRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/myubervm01715
```

Now we can use that to get the actual Network Interface object a couple ways, but the simplest is to just run `Get-AzureRmResource` against it, and pipe that to `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface`.

```
$NIs = $VM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id|%{Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_}|Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface
```

That will get you a collection of Network Interface objects. Each of these will have several properties, but the one we care about is the IpConfigurations property. Each IpConfig of each Network Interface will have a PrivateIpAddress property, and a PublicIp property. The PrivateIp property is just a string, so we can use that, but the PublicIp is an object, so we will need to refer to it's IpAddress property. Now, this is going to potentially return more than one of each of those depending on how many network interfaces you have associated with a given VM, so I'll join them with ', ' just to be safe. To break that down, we can do:

```
$PrivateIps = $NIs.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress -join ', '
$PublicIps = $NIs.IpConfigurations.PublicIp.IpAddress -join ', '
```

Thus ends the walk-through of getting the IPs for an Azure VM. That takes care of 2 of your suggested columns. Admittedly, two of the harder ones, but still just 2 of them none the less. Once you go through and get all of the data you need for each individual VM I'd make a custom object for it, and output those custom objects to your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, `get-azurermvm` could get all vms in your subscription, but you could not get detailed properties. You could use `Get-AzurermVM get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vm.Name` to get detailed properties.  You could try to use the following scripts.

```
##resource group name
$rg="<>"
$vms=get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $rg
ForEach ($vm in $vms) {
get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vm.Name
}
```

Note: You could use `get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName $rg -Status` to get VM's status information.

Comment: Even specifying the VM by the full ResourceId will not get you all of the  details they want. This is not as simple as running a single command.